# Cordova - Media Plugin - Intel XDK - IOS build fail

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, build, intel

I'm building an app with Intel XDK & the Ionic Ui which uses the cordova media plugin, building the app for android devices does work, but for IOS it doesn't. When i disable the plugin the build works brilliant on ios.

I looked into the building log, when it failed:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/Parookaville.build/Release-iphoneos/Parookaville.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVSound.o Parookaville/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/CDVSound.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/Parookaville.build/Release-iphoneos/Parookaville.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/CDVSound.o Parookaville/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/CDVSound.m normal armv7s objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/Parookaville.build/Release-iphoneos/Parookaville.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVSound.o Parookaville/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/CDVSound.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(3 failures)
Command finished with error code 65: .../parooka/platforms/ios/cordova/build --release,--device
Error: .../parooka/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Developer/cordova/4.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Does someone of you know, why it isn't working ?

Thanks & cheers